# pyspark dataframe returning different characters \"\" instead of nulls

Tags: pyspark, null

I was reading a fixed with file from hadoop and doing substr and converting it to delimiter file. Code is working fine but instead of emply values in case of null it is returning \"\". Could you please suggest?

snippet

```
df.select(
df.value.substr(31, 1).alias('status'),
df.value.substr(32, 1).alias('tin_cert'),
df.value.substr(116, 1).alias('c_notice_flg'),
df.value.substr(117, 2).alias('nbr_non_prime_trlrs'),
df.value.substr(119, 3).alias('aw_related')
).write.option("delimiter", "|").csv(unixFile)
```

output

|\"\"|0|N|00|\"\"|199|

desired output

||0|N|00||199|

no quotes in the input file

000000000014999999999         281AAAA AAAAAAA AAAA                                                               1NN00
000000000024                  200BBBBB BBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBB                                                         0NN00
000000000034                  200                                                                                0NN00
000000000044                  200                                                                                0NN00

Comment: can you also provide your input data

Comment: if you `\"\"` it simply means that you have double quotes in your text. So spark is using the \ char as an escape char.

Comment: added input file..it removed spaces but input fixed width file has no quotes

Answer (score 0):

I think escaped quotes are added because of default arguments for `pyspark.sql.DataFrameWriter.csv` method. In fact, as you can see from the [docs](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.DataFrameWriter.csv):

> quote – sets a single character used for escaping quoted values where the separator can be part of the value. **If None is set, it uses the default value, `"`.** If an empty string is set, it uses `u0000` (null character).
>
> escape – sets a single character used for escaping quotes inside an already quoted value. **If None is set, it uses the default value, `\`**